# What to use instead of modulus?

Tags: c, if-statement, modulus

I am writing a program that simulates a round robin style cpu scheduler. After `timestamp` (variable input in the command line) number of time units, the scheduler should move that process down to the bottom of the queue and resume with the next node.

I am having trouble trying to calculate when I am at the end of a cycle, I tried with modulus first but I realized that was bad. I then tried using the literal calculation, and even threw in float casts but it still does not work. The statement is true when the worked attibute is 0, and is false at all other values of worked.

What I have tried:

```
if ((queue->worked % timestamp) != 0)
if ((queue->worked - (timestamp * (queue->worked / timestamp))) == 0)
if ((float) (queue->worked - (float) (timestamp * (float) (queue->worked / timestamp))) == 0)
```

I would also like to know if there is a better way of doing this so that I can avoid the modulus altogether.

Below is some of the relevant code:

```
struct node {
    double process_id;
    int arrival_time;
    int cpu_time;
    int worked;
    struct node *nextElement;
};

void round_robin(nodeptr firstNode, int timestamp) {
    nodeptr queue = firstNode;

    if ((queue->worked % timestamp) == 0) {
        queue->worked++;
        current_time++;
    }
    else {
        tmpptr = queue;
        queue = queue->nextElement;
        add_to_bottom(tmpptr, queue);
    }
}
```

Here is a set of samples. These are lines in a text file that are read in by the main function and are stored as a linked list of nodes.

```
 2001  0  20
 2002  1  10
 2005  2  15
 2007  3   4
```

where the columns represent the process id, the arrival time, and time the process will take to calculate (in milliseconds).

A pointer to the first node (process 2001) is passed to the function as well as an integer that was passed as an argument (./main 10)

The function iterates over the list and simulates a round robin style cpu scheduler.

Step by step:
So if I input 10 for timestamp: (output is not important right now)

```
Process 2001 should calculate for 10 milliseconds, then get send to the back of the list.
Process 2002 will calculate for 10 and finish.
Process 2005 will calculate for 10 milliseconds, get send to the back.
Process 2007 will calculate for 4 and be done.
Process 2001 was went to the back and now runs for 10 more and finishes.
Process 2005 calculates for the remaining 5 and the program is now done.
```

Edit:

I added a printf that said "If!\n" in the if and one that said "Else!\n" in the else and it prints out if once (worked is initialized to 0) and then else every other time that node is run. It only enters the if for a value of zero, after worked is incremented it does not enter again and gets stuck in an infinite loop of putting the first process to the end.

```
If!
Else!
If!
Else!
If!
Else!
If!
Else!
Else!
Else!
Else!
...until it eventually segfaults after about 900 lines
```

Comment: *I tried with modulus first but I realized that was bad.* - Why is it "bad?"  Please define "didn't work."

Comment: @EdS. The modulus command does not work the same in all languages, depending on the definition of an integer. All the statements calculate to be true when the worked attibute is 0, and is false at all other values of worked.

Comment: Why not `if(queue->worked != timestamp) ...`?

Comment: @xjsc16x: That seems unlikely; what is the value of `timestamp`?  Can you provide a test-case that demonstrates this?

Comment: I'm still not clear on the desired behaviour of your if statement. Can you post a table of inputs, with desired true/false results?

Comment: edited to add examples, sorry

Comment: It's not clear how that set of samples corresponds to the activity of your program.  Please edit your code sample to show what and where you are printing, and then add both the obtained and desired results.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I edited again to explain the program in more detail.

Comment: Ok, but what *actually* happens when you run this?  If you add some useful printfs to your code, what do you observe?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added a printf that said "If!\n" in the if and one that said "Else!\n" in the else and it prints out if once (worked is initialized to 0) and then else every other time that node is run. It only enters the if for a value of zero, after worked is incremented it does not enter again and gets stuck in an infinite loop of putting the first process to the end.

Comment: I suggest you also get it to print out the current value of `queue->worked` each time.

Answer (score 1):

`%` in C is not modulus but remainder. Don't use it on signed types like `int` if you don't know what it is doing. Perhaps your worries would cease if you'd change your `int` members to `unsigned`. On `unsigned` you have a guarantee that `a % b` always falls in the range `0`..`b-1`.